# oracle reports parameter width on application server

Tags: parameters, oraclereports, oracle-application-server

I have Oracle Report in 10g and a parameter form like this
[image]

Problem is that when I throw this report on application server and test it In Internet Explorer or Chrome the Width of Top Parameter Extends 5 Times of Original Width Like this

[image]

Can Any Any One Tell Me What and Why this Problem Occuring Why the Width Of A parameter Exceeds from its Original Width.Plz Help !

Comment: anyone can Give the answer

Comment: Check property of parameter. Width parameter in particular.